# Wix installer creates new entry instead of upgrading existing msi

Tags: wix, upgrade

My Bundle exe has following code

```
<PackageGroup Id="MyWeb">
          <MsiPackage SourceFile="Release\en-us\MyWeb.msi" Cache="no" Id="MyWebMSI" Compressed="yes" ForcePerMachine="yes"   Vital="yes" DisplayName="My WEB">
            <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[InstallFolder]"/>
            <MsiProperty Name="MyWebPORT" Value="[MyWebPORTNO]"/>
            <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLCERTIFICATES" Value="[DOINSTALLCERTIFICATES]"/>
          </MsiPackage>
        </PackageGroup>
```

MyWeb.msi is again a wix installer with below code:

```
<Product  Id="*" UpgradeCode="442a9a72-ada7-4c68-b77f-feb99e67a23a"
            Version="!(bind.FileVersion.filename)"
            Name="!(loc.ProductName)"
            Language="!(loc.LANG)"
            Manufacturer="!(loc.ManufacturerName)">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" InstallPrivileges="elevated" 
             Languages="!(loc.LANG)"
             Manufacturer="!(loc.CompanyName)" Comments="!(loc.Comments)"
             Description="!(loc.Description)" Keywords="!(loc.Keywords)"/>
    <MajorUpgrade AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
</Product>
<Fragment>
...
</Fragment>
```

However, While upgrading my bundle exe, instead of upgrading my msi installer creates new entry[image]

I want my msi to get updated and not a new entry to be created in Add/Remove Programs

Comment: what is the value of `UpgradeCode` of the other package? these should match.

Comment: `UpgradeCode` is same for both the packages

Comment: can you post the msi log somewhere?